# Flutter: BitmapDescriptor.fromAsset deprecated

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps-markers, deprecated, google-maps-flutter

I'm new to Flutter and I have this code in my app that works perfect to populate a markers list with thousands of items having each of them one of 4 available icons stored locally as png files:

```
        for (var bla in jData) {
          LatLng _markerPos =
            LatLng(
              double.parse(bla['lat']),
              double.parse(bla['lng'])
            );
          String _iconImage = 'assets/images/' + bla['q'].toString() + '.png';
          markers.add(Marker(
            position: _markerPos,
            markerId: MarkerId(bla['hash']),
            icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromAsset(_iconImage)
          ));
        }
```

But now the **fromAsset** method has been deprecated and the new way to assign a BitmapDescriptor seems to be through a Future function which throws an error* (Also sounds to me like a lot of trouble for something that can be done so easily the old way).

So could anyone please help me achieve this with the new method **fromAssetImage**? It seems weird to me to assign a Future inside a for loop but I'm a noob.

**This is the error I get with the new method***: The argument type 'Future' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BitmapDescriptor'. (argument_type_not_assignable at [flutter_app] lib/lash.dart:81)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `fromAsset` method was a synchronous call to get a `Bitmap` object, but now it has been replaced by the `fromAssetImage` asynchronous method, I guess it is because of responsiveness and performance-related issues.

Although it looks like it is a new topic for you, it should be easy to get your piece of code working with [asynchronous programming](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await), you just need to tag your loop as `async`, and then `await` the `fromAssetImage` object return before using it in your marker. Something like this should work, although I have not tried it.

```dart
         for (var bla in jData) async {
          LatLng _markerPos =
            LatLng(
              double.parse(bla['lat']),
              double.parse(bla['lng'])
            );
          String _iconImage = 'assets/images/' + bla['q'].toString() + '.png';
          final bitmapIcon = await BitmapDescriptor.fromAsset(_iconImage);
          markers.add(Marker(
            position: _markerPos,
            markerId: MarkerId(bla['hash']),
            icon: bitmapIcon
          ));
        }
```

Comment: Thanks mate! that does make a lot of sense, I'm gonna give a deeper look at async functions!!

Comment: The answer is still with fromAsset, not fromAssetImage...